# Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ado

Does anyone know why the following SQL statement returns the above error?

sSQL="INSERT INTO Table_Name (field_name) VALUES (""'" & Request.Form(POSTval) & "'"")"

POSTVal should contain a string from the first form textbox since this query is only called by a if statement to ensure that we're at the right spot. Thanks!

P.S. Using a MS Access DB

Comment: fyi - building your query that way creates a huge security hole in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would try:

```
myinsert= Request.Form("POSTval")
sSQL="INSERT INTO Table_Name (field_name) VALUES ('" & myinsert & "')"
```

You might also verify that Request.Form("POSTval") has a value and is not NULL.

Comment: Nope, no change...any other ideas?

Comment: Yes.  Verify that the field in your database is text and not a number type.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue. I didn't realize there was a design view for Access DB tables themselves and realized within this view that the field in question was, unlike all the others, set to AutoNumber instead of text. Changing the field type to text solved my problem.

Comment: @user578086   Please consider accepting my answwer.  I could use the points.

Answer (score 0):

Request.Form is a Map, and the keys are Strings, then you have to use quotes.

```
Request.Form("POSTval")
```

Comment: Doing that command with or without quotation marks makes no difference. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I supose that your form is using the Post Method and the POSTval field is assigned (hidden field o form element like textbox, etc.). Is that right?